General Purpose Utility Constants, Macros, and Functions
Overview:
I have bundled together different macros and functions I often require in different projects into a single compilation unit (utils.h and util.c). The API provides utilities for string manipulation, type traits, C++ like casts, range macros, assertion control, compile-time evaluation, array size determination, debugging and conditional execution, generic macros, et cetera.
Everything has been documented in descriptive words in the below header, so I have not been described much here (DRY?). cloc showed 105 blank, 480 comment, and 533 code lines for the below header.
The type traits have already been reviewed here, so they can be ignored.
Code:
C11's _Generic() and C23's typeof have been used judiciously. Where needed, external reference to StackOverflow have been provided in the documentation.
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H 1

#include <complex.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>

/* Would these be better as `static constexpr unsigned char`s? */
#define CHARIFY_0   '0' 
#define CHARIFY_1   '1'
#define CHARIFY_2   '2' 
#define CHARIFY_3   '3'
#define CHARIFY_4   '4'
#define CHARIFY_5   '5'
#define CHARIFY_6   '6'
#define CHARIFY_7   '7'
#define CHARIFY_8   '8'
#define CHARIFY_9   '9'
#define CHARIFY_A   'A'
#define CHARIFY_B   'B'
#define CHARIFY_C   'C'
#define CHARIFY_D   'D'
#define CHARIFY_E   'E'
#define CHARIFY_F   'F'
#define CHARIFY_G   'G'
#define CHARIFY_H   'H'
#define CHARIFY_I   'I'
#define CHARIFY_J   'J'
#define CHARIFY_K   'K'
#define CHARIFY_L   'L'
#define CHARIFY_M   'M'
#define CHARIFY_N   'N'
#define CHARIFY_O   'O'
#define CHARIFY_P   'P'
#define CHARIFY_Q   'Q'
#define CHARIFY_R   'R'
#define CHARIFY_S   'S'
#define CHARIFY_T   'T'
#define CHARIFY_U   'U'
#define CHARIFY_V   'V'
#define CHARIFY_W   'W'
#define CHARIFY_X   'X'
#define CHARIFY_Y   'Y'
#define CHARIFY_Z   'Z'
#define CHARIFY__   '_'
#define CHARIFY_a   'a'
#define CHARIFY_b   'b'
#define CHARIFY_c   'c'
#define CHARIFY_d   'd'
#define CHARIFY_e   'e'
#define CHARIFY_f   'f'
#define CHARIFY_g   'g'
#define CHARIFY_h   'h'
#define CHARIFY_i   'i'
#define CHARIFY_j   'j'
#define CHARIFY_k   'k'
#define CHARIFY_l   'l'
#define CHARIFY_m   'm'
#define CHARIFY_n   'n'
#define CHARIFY_o   'o'
#define CHARIFY_p   'p'
#define CHARIFY_q   'q'
#define CHARIFY_r   'r'
#define CHARIFY_s   's'
#define CHARIFY_t   't'
#define CHARIFY_u   'u'
#define CHARIFY_v   'v'
#define CHARIFY_w   'w'
#define CHARIFY_x   'x'
#define CHARIFY_y   'y'
#define CHARIFY_z   'z'

#define CONCAT2_INDIRECT(A, B)      A ## B
#define STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(A)       #A

/**
 * Concatenate A to B together to form a single token. */
#define CONCAT2(A, B)               CONCAT2_INDIRECT(A, B)

/**
 * Macro that "char-ifies" its argument, e.g., CHARIFY(x) becomes 'x'.
 *
 * X can only be in the set [0-9_A-Za-z]. */
#define CHARIFY(X)                  CONCAT2(CHARIFY_, X)

/**
 * Macro that "string-ifies" its argument, e.g., STRINGIFY(x) becomes "x".
 *
 * X - The unquoted string to stringify. */
#define STRINGIFY(X)                STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(X)

/**
 * Synthesises a name prefixed by PREFIX unique to the line on which it is used.
 *
 * Notes: 
 * 1) All uses for a given PREFIX that refer to the same name must be on the same
 *    line. This is not a problem within macro definitions, but would not work
 *    outside of them since there is no way to refer to a previously used unique
 *    name. But if the intent is to have multiple "unique" names on a single line,
 *    the value of PREFIX must be different. 
 *
 * 2) If UNIQUE_NAME is used within a macro and that macro does not expose
 *    PREFIX (but picks one), then using the macro twice on the same line
 *    (possibly nested, as in MAX(a, MAX(b, c)) ) will cause different
 *    variables to end up with the same unique names.
 *
 * This is generally useful in macros to avoid any conflict with existing
 * identifiers, and also because having a unique name allows you to use the
 * same macro multiple times in the same scope or nested scopes and avoid
 * "shadows" warnings. */
#define UNIQUE_NAME(PREFIX)         CONCAT2(CONCAT2(PREFIX, _), __LINE__)     

/**
 * C version of C++'s const_char.
 *
 * T    - The type to cast to.
 * EXPR - The expression to cast.
 *
 * Note: This macro can not actually implement C++'s const char because there 
 * is no way to do it in C. It merely serves as a visual cue for the type of 
 * cast meant. */
#define CONST_CAST(T, EXPR)         ((T)(EXPR))

/**
 * C version of C++'s static_cast. 
 *
 * T    - The type to cast to.
 * EXPR - The expression to cast.
 *
 * Note: This macro can not actually implement C++'s static_cast because there
 * is no way to do it in C. It serves merely as a visual cue for the type of
 * cast meant. */
#define STATIC_CAST(T, EXPR)        ((T)(EXPR))

/**
 * Cast either from or to an integral type --- similar to C++'s 
 * reinterpret_cast, but for integers only.
 *
 * T    - The type to cast to.
 * EXPR - The expression to cast.
 *
 * Note: In C++, this would be done via reinterpret_cast, but it is not
 * posible to implement that in C that works for both pointers and integers. */
#define INTEGER_CAST(T, EXPR)       ((T)(uintmax_t)(EXPR))

/**
 * Cast either from or to a pointer type --- similar to C++'s
 * reinterpret_cast, but for pointers only.
 *
 * T    - The type to cast to.
 * EXPR - The expression to cast.
 *
 * Note: This macro silences a "cast to pointer from integer of different size"
 * warning. In C++, this would be done via reinterpret_cast, but it is not
 * possible to implement that in C that works for both pointers and integers. */
#define POINTER_CAST(T, EXPR)       ((T)(uintptr_t)(EXPR))

/**
 * Expands to 1 (true) if VAL is within the range of LO to HI (inclusive),
 * else 0 (false).
 *
 * Note: RANGE() evaluates VAL_ more than once. */
#define RANGE(VAL, LO, HI)   \
    (((VAL) >= (LO)) && ((VAL) <= (HI)))

/**
 * Expands to 1 (true) if VAL is within the range of LO to HI (exclusive),
 * else 0 (false).
 *
 * Note: RANGE() evaluates VAL more than once. */ 
#define RANGEM1(VAL, LO, HI) \
    (((VAL) >= (LO)) && ((VAL) < (HI)))

/**
 * Embeds the given statements into a compound statement block. */
#define BLOCK(...)                  do { __VA_ARGS__ } while (false)

/**
 * To enable debugging trace, define DEBUG. */
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define TRACE_ON    1
#else
    #define TRACE_ON    0
#endif

/**
 * When debugging trace is enabled, TRACE() prints to stderr with the formatted
 * message, source file name, line number, and function name. 
 *
 * FMT - The printf() format string literal to use.
 * ... - The printf() arguments. */
#define TRACE(FMT, ...)                                             \
    BLOCK(                                                          \
        if (TRACE_ON) {                                             \
            /* "" provides rudimentary type-checking. */            \
            fprintf(stderr, "%s::%d::%s():: " FMT "", __FILE__,     \
                    __LINE__, __func__, __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__); \
        }                                                           \
    )

/**
 * Asserts that this line of code is run at most once --- useful in
 * initialization functions that must be called at most once. For example:
 *
 *     void initialize(void) {
 *         ASSERT_RUN_ONCE();
 *         // ...
 *     } 
 *
 * Note: This implementation is not thread-safe. */
#ifndef NDEBUG
    #define ASSERT_RUN_ONCE()                   \
        BLOCK(                                  \
            static bool UNIQUE_NAME(called);    \
            assert(!UNIQUE_NAME(called));       \
            UNIQUE_NAME(called) = true;         \
        )
#else
    #define ASSERT_RUN_ONCE()       (void)0
#endif  /* NDEBUG */

/**
 * Convenience macro for iterating N times. */
#define FOR_N_TIMES(N)                                                        \
    for (size_t UNIQUE_NAME(i) = 0;                                           \
         UNIQUE_NAME(i) < STATIC_CAST(size_t, (N));                           \
         STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(IS_INTEGRAL(N), #N " must be an integral type."), \
         ++UNIQUE_NAME(i))

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether an expression is compatible with a type.
 *
 * EXPR - An expression. It is not evaluted.
 * T    - The type to check against.
 *
 * Note: Only an expression can be compared with a type. Two expressions or 
 * two type names can not be directly compared. 
 *
 * To compare two types, a compound literal can be used to create a literal of
 * a given type like so:
 *     
 *     IS_COMPATIBLE((size_t){0}, unsigned long);
 *
 * To test two variables for type compatibility, typeof can be used like so:
 *     
 *     IS_COMPATIBLE(x, typeof(y));
 *
 * Also note that this would not work for arrays, nor when one argument is a
 * pointer and another an array.
 *
 * Returns to 1 (true) if EXPR is compatible with T, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_COMPATIBLE(EXPR, T) \
    _Generic((EXPR),           \
        T      : 1,            \
        default: 0             \
    )     

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether T has type nullptr_t.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluted. 
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if T is the type nullptr_t, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_NULLPTR(T) \
    _Generic((T),     \
        nullptr_t: 1, \
        default  : 0  \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether T has type FILE *.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluted. 
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if T is the type FILE *, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_FILE_PTR(T) \
    _Generic((T),      \
        FILE * : 1,    \
        default: 0     \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether T is an array.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluted. 
 *
 * Note: IS_ARRAY() distinguishes between arrays and pointers, not between
 *       arrays and arbitrary other types.
 * 
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is an array; 0 (false) elsewise. 
 *
 * See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881417/99089 */
#define IS_ARRAY(T)                 \
    _Generic( &(T),                 \
        typeof(*T) (*)[]    : 1,    \
        default             : 0     \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether A is a pointer.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluted. 
 *
 * Note: IS_POINTER() distinguishes between arrays and pointers, not between
 *       pointers and arbitrary other types.
 * 
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a pointer; 0 (false) elsewise. 
 *
 * See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881417/99089 */
#define IS_POINTER(T)   !IS_ARRAY(T)

/**
 * Implements a "static if" similar to "if constexpr" in C++.
 *
 * EXPR - An expression (evaluated at compile-time).
 * THEN - An expression returned only if EXPR is non-zero (true).
 * ELSE - An expression returned only if EXPR is zero (false).
 *
 * Returns:
 *     THEN only if EXPR is non-zero (true); or:
 *     ELSE only if EXPR is zero (false). */
#define STATIC_IF(EXPR, THEN, ELSE)     \
    _Generic( &(char[1 + !!(EXPR)]){0}, \
        char (*)[2]: (THEN),            \
        char (*)[1]: (ELSE)             \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether char is signed or unsigned.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if char is signed, else 0 (false). */
#define IS_CHAR_SIGNED          STATIC_IF((char)-1 < 0, 1, 0)

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether sig_atomic_t is signed or unsigned.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if sig_atomic_t is signed, else 0 (false). */
#define IS_SIG_ATOMIC_T_SIGNED  STATIC_IF((sig_atomic_t)-1 < 0, 1, 0)

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether wint_t is signed or unsigned.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if wint_t is signed, else 0 (false). */
#define IS_WINT_T_SIGNED        STATIC_IF((wint_t)-1 < 0, 1, 0)

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether wchar_t is signed or unsigned.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if wchar_t is signed, else 0 (false). */
#define IS_WCHAR_T_SIGNED       STATIC_IF((wchar_t)-1 < 0, 1, 0)

#define IS_SIGNED15(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        wchar_t               : IS_WCHAR_T_SIGNED,      \
        default               : 0                       \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED14(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        wint_t                : IS_WINT_T_SIGNED,       \
        default               : IS_SIGNED15(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED13(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        sig_atomic_t          : IS_SIG_ATOMIC_T_SIGNED, \
        default               : IS_SIGNED14(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED12(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_fast64_t          : 1,                      \
        default               : IS_SIGNED13(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED11(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_fast32_t          : 1,                      \
        default               : IS_SIGNED12(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED10(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_fast16_t          : 1,                      \
        default               : IS_SIGNED11(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED9(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_fast8_t           : 1,                      \
        default               : IS_SIGNED10(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED8(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_least64_t          : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED9(T)          \
    )
#define IS_SIGNED7(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_least32_t          : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED8(T)          \
    )
#define IS_SIGNED6(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_least16_t          : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED7(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED5(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int_least8_t           : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED6(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED4(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        int8_t                 : 1,                     \
        int16_t                : 1,                     \
        int32_t                : 1,                     \
        int64_t                : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED5(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED3(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        intptr_t               : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED4(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED2(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        intmax_t               : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED3(T)          \
    )

#define IS_SIGNED1(T)                                   \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        ptrdiff_t              : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED2(T)          \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check whether the type of T is a signed type. 
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated. 
 *
 * Note: This would not detect _BitInt. 
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a signed type; 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_SIGNED(T)                                    \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        char                   : IS_CHAR_SIGNED,        \
        short int              : 1,                     \
        int                    : 1,                     \
        long int               : 1,                     \
        long long int          : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_SIGNED1(T)          \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED15(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        wchar_t               : !IS_WCHAR_T_SIGNED,     \
        default               : 0                       \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED14(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        wint_t                : !IS_WINT_T_SIGNED,      \
        default               : IS_UNSIGNED15(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED13(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        sig_atomic_t          : !IS_SIG_ATOMIC_T_SIGNED,\
        default               : IS_UNSIGNED14(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED12(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_fast64_t          : 1,                     \
        default               : IS_UNSIGNED13(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED11(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_fast32_t          : 1,                     \
        default               : IS_UNSIGNED12(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED10(T)                                \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_fast16_t          : 1,                     \
        default               : IS_UNSIGNED11(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED9(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_fast8_t           : 1,                     \
        default               : IS_UNSIGNED10(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED8(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_least64_t          : 1,                    \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED9(T)        \
    )
#define IS_UNSIGNED7(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_least32_t          : 1,                    \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED8(T)        \
    )
#define IS_UNSIGNED6(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_least16_t          : 1,                    \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED7(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED5(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint_least8_t           : 1,                    \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED6(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED4(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uint8_t                : 1,                     \
        uint16_t               : 1,                     \
        uint32_t               : 1,                     \
        uint64_t               : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED5(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED3(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uintptr_t              : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED4(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED2(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        uintmax_t              : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED3(T)        \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED1(T)                                 \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        size_t                 : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED2(T)        \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether the type of T is a unsigned type. 
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated. 
 *
 * Note: This would not detect _BitInt. 
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a unsigned type; 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_UNSIGNED(T)                                  \
    _Generic((T),                                       \
        _Bool                  : 1,                     \
        char                   : !IS_CHAR_SIGNED,       \
        unsigned char          : 1,                     \
        unsigned short int     : 1,                     \
        unsigned int           : 1,                     \
        unsigned long int      : 1,                     \
        unsigned long long int : 1,                     \
        default                : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)        \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether the type of T is any integral type. 
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated. 
 *
 * Note: This would not detect _BitInt.
 * 
 * Returns 1 (true) if T is any integral type, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_INTEGRAL(T)  (IS_SIGNED(T) || IS_UNSIGNED(T))

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether the type of T is a floating-point type.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated. 
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) if T is a floating-point type, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#if defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__)         \
    && defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_COMPLEX__)  \
    && defined(_Imaginary_I)
    #define IS_FLOATING_POINT(T)            \
        _Generic((T),                       \
            float                 : 1,      \
            double                : 1,      \
            long double           : 1,      \
            float _Complex        : 1,      \
            double _Complex       : 1,      \
            long double _Complex  : 1,      \
            float _Imaginary      : 1,      \
            double _Imaginary     : 1,      \
            long double _Imaginary: 1,      \
            _Decimal32            : 1,      \
            _Decimal64            : 1,      \
            _Decimal128           : 1,      \
            default               : 0       \
        )
#elif defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_COMPLEX__)   \
      && defined(_Imaginary_I)              \
      && !defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__)
    #define IS_FLOATING_POINT(T)            \
        _Generic((T),                       \
            float                 : 1,      \
            double                : 1,      \
            long double           : 1,      \
            float _Complex        : 1,      \
            double _Complex       : 1,      \
            long double _Complex  : 1,      \
            float _Imaginary      : 1,      \
            double _Imaginary     : 1,      \
            long double _Imaginary: 1,      \
            default               : 1       \
        )
#elif defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_COMPLEX__)   \
      && defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__)    \
      && !defined(_Imaginary_I)
    #define IS_FLOATING_POINT(T)            \
        _Generic((T),                       \
            float                 : 1,      \
            double                : 1,      \
            long double           : 1,      \
            float _Complex        : 1,      \
            double _Complex       : 1,      \
            long double _Complex  : 1,      \
            _Decimal32            : 1,      \
            _Decimal64            : 1,      \
            _Decimal128           : 1,      \
            default               : 0       \
        )
#elif defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__) && !defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_COMPLEX__)
    #define IS_FLOATING_POINT(T)            \
        _Generic((T),                       \
            float               : 1,        \
            double              : 1,        \
            long double         : 1,        \
            _Decimal32          : 1,        \
            _Decimal64          : 1,        \
            _Decimal128         : 1,        \
            default             : 0         \
        )
#elif defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_COMPLEX__) && !defined(__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__)
    #define IS_FLOATING_POINT(T)            \
        _Generic((T),                       \
            float                 : 1,      \
            double                : 1,      \
            long double           : 1,      \
            float _Complex        : 1,      \
            double _Complex       : 1,      \
            long double _Complex  : 1,      \
            default               : 0       \
        )
#else
    #define IS_FLOATING_POINT(T)            \
        _Generic((T),                       \
            float      : 1,                 \
            double     : 1,                 \
            long double: 1,                 \
            default    : 0                  \
        )
#endif

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether the type of T is any arithmetic type. 
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated. 
 *
 * Note: This would not detect _BitInt.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a C is any arithmetic type, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_ARITHMETIC(T)    (IS_INTEGRAL(T) || IS_FLOATING_POINT(T))

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether the type of T is a C string type, i.e. char *, 
 * or char const *.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a C string type, 0 (false) elsewise. */
#define IS_C_STR(T)         \
    _Generic((T),           \
        char *      : 1,    \
        char const *: 1,    \
        default     : 0     \
    )

/** 
 * Compile-time of whether the type of T is compatible with the type of an 
 * array of length N.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated.
 * N - Length of array.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is compatible with array of length N, 0 (false)
 * elsewise. */
#define IS_COMPATIBLE_WITH_ARRAY_OF_LENGTH_N(T, N)  \
    _Generic(&(T),                                  \
        typeof(*T) (*)[N]: 1,                       \
        default          : 0                        \
    )

/**
 * Compile-time of whether the type of T is variable-length array or an 
 * unspecified-length array.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a VLA or a ULA, 0 (false) elsewise.
 *
 * See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78597305/20017547 */
#define IS_VLA_OR_ULA(T)                            \
    (IS_COMPATIBLE_WITH_ARRAY_OF_LENGTH_N(T, 1)     \
    && IS_COMPATIBLE_WITH_ARRAY_OF_LENGTH_N(T, 2))

/**
 * Compile-time check of whether the type of T is a function type.
 *
 * T - An expression. It is not evaluated.
 *
 * Returns 1 (true) only if T is a function type, 0 (false) elsewise. 
 *
 * See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78601265/20017547 */
#define IS_FUNCTION(T)      \
    _Generic((T),           \
        typeof(T)*: true,   \
        default:    false   \
    )

/**
 * Like C11's _Static_assert() except that it can be used in an expression.
 *
 * EXPR - The expression to check.
 * MSG  - The string literal of the error message to print only if EXPR evalutes
 *        to false.
 *
 * Always returns true. */
#define STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(EXPR, MSG) \
    (!!sizeof( struct { static_assert ( (EXPR), MSG ); char c; } ))

/**
 * Gets the number of elements of the given array. */
#define ARRAY_CARDINALITY(ARRAY) (      \
    sizeof(ARRAY) / sizeof(0[ARRAY])    \
    * STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR( IS_ARRAY(ARRAY), #ARRAY " must be an array" ))

/**
 * Strips trailing linefeed from S.
 *
 * S - The C string to strip the linefeed from. 
 *
 * Note: STRIP_LF() evalutes S more than once. */
#define STRIP_LF(S) \
    (((S) + (STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(IS_C_STR(S), \
    #S " must be a C string") - 1))[strcspn((S), "\r\n")]  = '\0')

/**
 * Gets the length of S.
 *
 * S - The C string literal to get the length of. 
 *
 * Note: STRLITLEN() evalutes S more than once. */
#define STRLITLEN(S) \
    (ARRAY_CARDINALITY(S) - STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(IS_C_STR(S), \
    #S " must be a C string literal"))

/**
 * Advances S over all CHARS.
 *
 * S     - The C string pointer to advance.
 * CHARS - A C string containing the characters to skip over.
 * 
 * Returns the updated S. 
 *
 * Note: SKIP_CHARS() evalutes S more than once. */
#define SKIP_CHARS(S, CHARS) \
    ((S) += strspn((S), (CHARS)))

/**
 * Advances S over all whitespace.
 *
 * S - The string pointer to advance.
 *
 * Returns the updated S. 
 *
 * Note: SKIP_WS() evalutes S more than once. */
#define SKIP_WS(S) \
    SKIP_CHARS((S), " \n\t\r\f\v")

/**
 * Convenience macro for iterating over the elements of a fixed-length array.
 *
 * Note: Compound literal array is not a valid value for ARRAY.
 * 
 * VAR   - The element loop variable.
 * ARRAY - The array to iterate over. */
#define FOREACH_ARRAY_ELEMENT(VAR, ARRAY) \
    for (typeof(*ARRAY) const *VAR = (ARRAY); VAR < (ARRAY) + ARRAY_CARDINALITY(ARRAY); ++VAR)

/**
 * The machinery to vectorize any function that takes any type of pointer.
 *
 * TYPE - The type of pointer the function takes. For a function that takes in
 *        a void *, this shall be void.
 * FN   - The function to vectorize.
 * ...  - The arguments. */
#define FN_APPLY(TYPE, FN, ...)                         \
    BLOCK(                                              \
        void *stopper = (int[]){0};                     \
        TYPE **list = (TYPE*[]){ __VA_ARGS__, stopper}; \
        for (size_t i = 0; list[i]; i++) {              \
            STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(IS_FUNCTION(FN),         \
                #FN " should be a function.");          \
            FN(list[i]);                                \
        }                                               \
    )

/**
 * Calls the free() function individually on all arguments --- useful for
 * replacing multiple individual calls to free() like these:
 *
 *      free(a);
 *      free(b);
 *      free(c);
 *      free(d);
 */
#define FREE_ALL(...)               FN_APPLY(void, free, __VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * Initializes memory pointed to by a pointer with values of a specified type 
 * and number of elements. 
 *
 * PTR    - The pointer to memory to be initialized. 
 * TYPE   - The type of the elements.
 * NELEMS - The number of elements.
 * ...    - The elements. */
#define INIT(PTR, TYPE, NELEMS, ...) \
    memcpy(PTR, (TYPE []) {__VA_ARGS__}, NELEMS * sizeof(TYPE))

/**
 * Takes two type names (or expressions representing types) and evalutes to the
 * size (in bytes) of the larget type. 
 *
 * MAXSIZE() never evalutes either X or Y. */
#define MAXSIZE(X, Y)               (sizeof(X) > sizeof(Y) ? sizeof(X) : sizeof(Y))

/**
 * Takes two type names (or expressions representing types) and evalutes to the
 * size (in bytes) of the smaller type. 
 *
 * MINSIZE() never evalutes either X or Y. */
#define MINSIZE(X, Y)               (sizeof(X) < sizeof(Y) ? sizeof(X) : sizeof(Y))

/**
 * Copies the minimum of the sizes of T and S from S to T. */
#define BYTECOPY(T, S)              memcpy(&(T), &(S), MINSIZE(T, S))

/**
 * A special-case of INTERNAL_ERROR() that prints an unexpected integer value.
 *
 * EXPR - The expression having the unexpected value. */
#define UNEXPECTED_INT_VALUE(EXPR)                                    \
    INTERNAL_ERROR("%lld (0x%llX): unexpected value for " #EXPR "\n", \
            (long long)(EXPR), (unsigned long long)(EXPR))

/**
 * A special-case of fatal_error() that additionally prints the file, line,
 * and function name where an internal error occured.
 *
 * FMT - The printf() format string literal to use.
 * ... - The printf() arguments. */
#define INTERNAL_ERROR(FMT, ...)    \
    fatal_error("%s::%d::%s(): internal error: " FMT "", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
            __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * The macro to which FPRINTF dispatches in the absence of arguments. */
#define FPRINTF_II(STREAM, FMT) \
    fputs(FMT, STREAM)

/**
 * The macro to which FPRINTF dispatches in the presence of arguments. */
#define FPRINTF_III(STREAM, FMT, ...) \
    fprintf(STREAM, FMT "", __VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * Augments calls to fprintf() such that two types of problem are detected:
 * - If there is only a format argument and no others, we want to use fputs()
 *   to avoid scanning the format at execution time.
 * - If there are more than one arguments, it should be assured that the format
 *   is a string literal, such that the contents can be parsed at compiel time.
 *
 * STREAM - The stream to print to.
 * FMT    - The printf() format string to use. 
 *
 * If there were no arguments present beside FMT, then the return value is the
 * same as what fputs() would return, else if is what fprintf() would return. */
#define FPRINTF(STREAM, FMT, ...)                      \
    FPRINTF_II ## __VA_OPT__(I)                        \
    (STREAM + (STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(IS_FILE_PTR(STREAM), \
                #STREAM " must be a FILE *") - 1),     \
     FMT __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * Increases cap by 2x and returns it.
 *
 * If cap is less than 8, bumps it up to 8.
 *
 * double_capacity() does not check for overflow. */
[[reproducible, gnu::always_inline, gnu::const]] static inline size_t 
double_capacity(size_t cap);

/**
 * Increases cap by 1.5x and returns it.
 *
 * If cap is less than, bumps it up to 8.
 *
 * grow_capacity() does not check for overflow. */
[[reproducible, gnu::always_inline, gnu::const]] static inline size_t 
grow_capacity(size_t cap);

/* The semantics of reproducible and gnu::const are a little different, but
 * that difference is not relevant here. 
 *
 * Fall back to gnu::const if reproducible is not available, or vice versa. If
 * neither are recognized, they shall be ignored. */
[[reproducible, gnu::always_inline, gnu::const]] static inline size_t 
double_capacity(size_t cap)
{
    return cap < 8 ? 8 : cap * 2;
}

[[reproducible, gnu::always_inline, gnu::const]] static inline size_t 
grow_capacity(size_t cap)
{
    return cap < 8 ? 8 : cap * 3 / 2;
}

/**
 * Trims the memory region pointed by p to n bytes with realloc().
 *
 * Returns the trimmed memory region on success, or p on failure. */
[[gnu::always_inline]] static inline void *safe_trim(void *p, size_t n)
{
    void *const p2 = realloc(p, n);

    return p2 ? p2 : p;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * The functions util_asprintf() and util_vasprintf() are analogs of sprintf() 
 * and vsprintf(), except that they allocate a string large enough to hold the 
 * output including the terminating null byte ('\0'), and return a pointer to 
 * it via the first argument. This pointer should be passed to free() to release
 * the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.
 * 
 * strp - a pointer to the pointer that will hold the string.
 * fmt  - format string.
 * ...  - any arguments to fmt.
 *
 * When successful, these functions return the number of bytes printed, just 
 * like sprintf(). If memory allocation was not possible, or some other error 
 * occurs, these functions will return -1, and the contents of strp are unde‐
 * -fined. */
[[gnu::format(printf, 2, 3)]] int util_asprintf(char **restrict strp,
                                                const char fmt[restrict static 1], 
                                                ...); 

/**
 * See util_asprintf(). */
int util_vasprintf(char **restrict strp,
                   const char fmt[restrict static 1], 
                   va_list ap);

/**
 * The util_strnlen() function returns the number of bytes in the string 
 * pointed to by s, excluding the terminating null byte ('\0'), but at most 
 * n. In doing this, strnlen() looks only at the first n characters in the 
 * string pointed to by s and never beyond s[n - 1].
 *
 * Returns strlen(s), if that is less than n, or n if there is no null termi‐
 * -nating ('\0') among the first n characters pointed to by s. */
size_t util_strnlen(size_t n, const char s[static n]);

/**
 * The util_stpcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src (including 
 * the terminating null byte ('\0')) to the array pointed to by dest. The 
 * strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large 
 * enough to receive the copy.
 *
 * stpcpy() returns a pointer to the end of the string dest (that is, the 
 * address of the terminating null byte) rather than the beginning. */
[[gnu::returns_nonnull]] char *util_stpcpy(char dest[restrict static 1],
                                           const char src[restrict static 1]);

/* The util_basename() function break a null-terminated pathname string into 
 * filename component. 
 *
 * basename() returns the component following the final '/'. The behavior
 * is exactly the same as GNU's implementation of basename(). 
 *
 * The below function-like macro chooses which function to call based on the
 * type of s. If s is const-qualified, util_basename_const() is called and
 * a const-qualified pointer is returned. Else, util_basename_vanilla() is
 * called and a non-const-qualified pointer is returned. */
#define util_basename(s)                         \
    _Generic((s),                                \
            char *:       util_basename_vanilla, \
            const char *: util_basename_const)(s)

[[gnu::returns_nonnull]] char *util_basename_vanilla(char path[static 1]);

[[gnu::returns_nonnull]] const char *util_basename_const(const char path[static 1]);


/**
 * The util_strchrnul() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of 
 * the character c in the string s.
 * If c is not found in s, then it returns a pointer to the null byte at the 
 * end of s, rather than nullptr. 
 *
 * See util_basename() for how the purpose of the function-like macro below. */
#define util_strchrnul(s, c)                      \
    _Generic((s),                                 \
            char *:       util_strchrnul_vanilla, \
            const char *: util_strchrnul_const)(s, c)

[[gnu::pure, gnu::returns_nonnull]] char *util_strchrnul_vanilla(
        char s[static 1], 
        int c);

[[gnu::pure, gnu::returns_nonnull]] const char *util_strchrnul_const(
        const char s[static 1], 
        int c);

/**
 * The util_strcasecmp() function performs a byte-by-byte comparison of the 
 * strings s and t, ignoring the case of the characters. 
 *
 * It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s is 
 * found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than t. */
[[gnu::pure]] int util_strcasecmp(const char s[restrict static 1], 
                                  const char t[restrict static 1]);

/**
 * The util_memswap() function swaps the contents of two memory blocks pointed
 * by p1 and p2. The first argument, psize, gives the size of the memory blocks.
 *
 * Note that memswap() can not swap variables whose address can not be taken. */
[[gnu::nonnull]] void util_memswap(size_t psize,
                                   void *restrict p1, 
                                   void *restrict p2);

/**
 * Swaps the contents of A and B.
 *
 * Properties:
 *  - It evaluates each of A and B only once (sizeof does not evaluate its
 *    operand, except for VLAs, and _Generic does not evaluate its controlling
 *    expression).
 *  - It has a compile-time check for the correct sizes, and prints a nice,
 *    user-friendly error message if the sizes are different.
 *  - It has a compile-time check for compatible types, and prints a nice,
 *    user-friendly error message if the types are different.
 *  - It has no naming issue with a hidden variable.
 *  - The size of the temporary variable is computed at compile time, so the 
 *    compound literal is not a dynamic array.
 *  - It does not rely on VLAs, so it is more portable.
 *
 * Note: The expressions must allow the & operator to be applicable. Thus it 
 * will not work on variables that are declared with the register storage class.
 * Moreover, it would also not work with VLAs, and would invoke undefined
 * behavior if A and B are the same. */
#define SWAP(A, B)                                                         \
    util_memswap((sizeof *(1 ? &(A) : &(B))                                \
        * STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(sizeof (A) == sizeof (B),                     \
        "Arguments of SWAP() must have same size and compatible types.")), \
        &(A),                                                              \
        &(B))

/**
 * Swaps the contents of A and B.
 *
 * SWAP_GENERIC() differs from SWAP() in 2 ways:
 * - A VLA is a valid value for this macro.
 * - It does not have a compile-time check for same sizes, as the size of a VLA
 *   can not be computed at compile-time. */
#define SWAP_GENERIC(A, B) \
    util_memswap(sizeof *(1 ? &(A) : &B), &(A), &(B))

/**
 * Prints an error message to standard error and exists with EXIT_FAILURE.
 *
 * fmt - The printf() format string literal to use.
 * ... - The printf() arguments. */
[[noreturn, gnu::format(printf, 1, 2)]] void fatal_error(char fmt[static 1], ...);

#endif                          /* UTIL_H */

Tests:
800 lines of test code, not provided here due to the character limit getting exceeded.
You might wish to add -Wno-unused-value (to silence some warnings about the result of static assertion expressions going unused (they return 1, or true, if they do not cause a compilation failure)), Wno-type-limits (to quieten some useless conversion warnings), and -Wno-attributes (because GCC and Clang do not yet support C23's [[reproducible]] attribute) to the compiler flags if you compile the test code.
Routines not yet tested:

TRACE().
ASSERT_RUN_ONCE().
UNEXPECTED_INT_VALUE().
INTERNAL_ERROR().
FPRINTF().
fatal_error().

Problem being that they would cause compilation to fail if any internal static assertion failed. So I could not test them for failure. Similarly, the other routines containing static assertions have not been tested for failure. (I have done so separately, and am confident that they behave correctly.)
Review Request:
Well, how does one test that static_asserts have failed? Problems with the macros that have not been documented, multiple-evaluations that can be avoided, missing/wrong documentation, missing/wrong tests. C23 features that would be useful. Anything.
